# Dynamically append tables from different workbooks in Power Query

Tags: excel, append, powerquery

I'm trying to append several Excel tables from different workbooks using PowerQuery.

But instead of loading every table manually and then appending them, I would like to keep record of workbook names and tables along with their addresses in another table (say 'data_sources' table), so that PowerQuery could know what tables I want to append & where to find them.

How could I accomplish this? Suppose I have the following table, where other workbooks could be added later.

[image]

EDIT:

The following code will include to the query results any new column from the original tables. The `#"Added Custom"` argument will create a column containing the tables, and then it is used in the next step so to combine them.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="data_sources"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Workbook location", type text}, {"Workbook name", type text}, {"Table name", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Excel.Workbook(File.Contents([Workbook location]&[Workbook name])){[Item=[Table name],Kind="Table"]}[Data]),
    #"Combine" = Table.Combine(#"Added Custom"[Custom]),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Combine, each [Client] <> null and [Client] <> "")
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following input table, then the code below works to retrieve all tables and combine them. [image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Workbook Location", type text}, {"Workbook Name", type text}, {"Table Name", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Excel.Workbook(File.Contents([Workbook Location]&[Workbook Name]) ){[Item=[Table Name],Kind="Table"]}[Data])
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: This is close, but doesn't work. It gets the right number of rows, but instead of bringing the data from the tables, the code just repeats workbook and table names.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Check the code again and make sure you replace the variables correctly for [Workbook Name] and [Table Name] in the following line. 
   #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Excel.Workbook(File.Contents([Workbook Location]&[Workbook Name]) ){[Item=[Table Name],Kind="Table"]}[Data]),

Comment: I think the problem is in the #"Added Custom" argument. The query returns one row for every row of data in the tables, but instead of the actual data, it just repats the workbook's names.

Comment: Can you post your full query?

Comment: Sure, I've edit the question. I appreciate your review.

Comment: I see now. Remove the last step and expand the nested tables yourself. I'll update my code.

Comment: This works, thank you. However, any new columns won't be included in the query results.

Comment: Great. I think there are ways around that but you're probably best posting a new question.